# How to style Radiobutton list in jQueryMobile 1.4.2 with formatted content

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm trying to create something like the following in jQueryMobile 1.4.2 - i.e. a list of radio buttons with content to explain each option. This is a jquery screenshot from version 1.2 from [this great article best practices article.](http://roughlybrilliant.com/jquery_mobile_best_practices#6) The size of the description text is smaller than the body text.

[image]

However when I copy his sample code directly from  it comes out sized incorrectly like this (other controls shown for reference size).

[image]

Here's the sample code

```
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup"> 
    <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-1" id="radio-choice-1" value="choice-1" checked="checked" />
    <label for="radio-choice-1">
        <h3 class="ui-li-heading">jQuery Mobile</h3>
        <p class="ui-li-desc">Easy and great for all project from smartphones to dumbphones</p>
    </label>            

    <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-1" id="radio-choice-2" value="choice-2"  />          
    <label for="radio-choice-2">
        <h3 class="ui-li-heading">Sencha Touch</h3>
        <p class="ui-li-desc">Great for complex apps but a higher learning curve</p>
    </label>            

    <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-1" id="radio-choice-3" value="choice-3"  />          
    <label for="radio-choice-3">
        <h3 class="ui-li-heading">jQTouch</h3>
        <p class="ui-li-desc">Simple, lightweight, but focused on webkit</p>
    </label>            
</fieldset>
```

It turns out the reason the above code no longer works is that it references css class name `ul-li-desc` which **used** to be in [jquery mobile 1.2.1 css](http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.1/jquery.mobile-1.2.1.css) but is no longer in the latest [css for version 1.4.2](http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.css).

The new 1.4.2 version has sample code for something very similar in the [ListView component](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.2/listview/) that looks like this

[image]

The css class that reduces the size of the font here is `.ui-listview>li p`

So what's the correct way in jQuery Mobile 1.4.2 to create a radio button list with added content that isn't huge?

Comment: PS. Yes obviously I could just style it myself and have saved myself 20 minutes writing this question, but I'm trying to understand the css framework and do everything right from the start :-) Or should I be just sticking radio buttons in a ListView?

Comment: +1 for the comment ;) yup, you'll understand JQM once you start playing around with css. 1.4 is easier than previous version as the team has reduced amount of inner elements - e.g. `span` - that hold most of styles. Firebug controlgroup and start overriding/exploring :) ps. Even if you use listview, you'll need to override `li`'s `padding` at least.

Comment: here you go http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/4E485/

Comment: @omar - thanks. can u put this as a real answer so I can give you points

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to undetstand jQM CSS structure, is to firebug current view. jQM changes HTML markup based on *widget* as it adds extra elements and wraps others in order to each the final UI.

Bear in mind, you have to be specific and caucious when overriding jQM styles. Most of the *widgets* share the same classes (global classes).

Also note that as of jQM 1.4 to increase performance, the team has reduced the amount of *inner* elements that are you used for styling *widgets*.

```css
/* <p> within <label> */
label p {
  font-size: .9em;
  font-weight: 400;
  display: block;
}

/* <h3> & <p> within <label> */
label h3, label p {
  margin: .45em;
}

/* adjust position of radio button itself */
.ui-radio input, label.ui-btn:after {
  top: 35% !important;
}
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/4E485/)**

Comment: thanks Omar - look forward to working with you on my future questions :-) hehe

Comment: @Simon_Weaver you're welcome! I too looking forward to assisting you, it will be a pleasure :)